# what if I ignore the return value of a function with shared_ptr return type

Tags: c++, return-value, shared-ptr, raii

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

shared_ptr<string> func()
{
    shared_ptr<string> ptr = make_shared<string>("smart poiter");
    return ptr;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    func();
    cout << "pause" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

like code above, will the memory of string "smart poiter" be released?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. `shared_ptr`s aren't special here; *any* instance's destructor will be invoked promptly (when the statement finishes evaluation) if the instance is returned without being assigned; not doing so would break RAII in a critical way. `shared_ptr`'s destructor decrements the reference count, no other instances own a reference, so the destructor will release the associated memory.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. The internal counter will reach `0` and the memory will be released safely.